# R specific combinations of number variables to calculate continuation rate

Tags: r, dplyr

The code I have so far:

```
continuation <- data %>%
  filter(TYPE == "group") %>%
  select(ID, YEAR, COURSE_YEAR) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  distinct(COURSE_YEAR) %>%
  summarise(number = n())
```

Some sample data:

| ID | YEAR | COURSE_YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123545 | 2019 | 1 |
| 123545 | 2020 | 2 |
| 123654 | 2019 | 1 |
| 119236 | 2019 | 2 |
| 116787 | 2019 | 3 |
| 113435 | 2019 | 2 |
| 113435 | 2020 | 3 |

So I would want results something like

| Year | Course Years | No. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 1 | 1 |
| 2019 | 1, 2 | 1 |
| 2019 | 2 | 1 |
| 2019 | 3 | 1 |
| 2019 | 2, 3 | 1 |

Course year has a range of values between 1 and 4.
The distinct is needed as people may have multiple entries in the type column for each course year due to the nature of the underlying data.

I am trying to work out, for each of the years in the data set, how many ID numbers appear for the first time, and what combinations of course year there are. So I would expect most of the people appearing for the first time to have a course year of 1, but I'm interested in whether they are appearing in the data set for later years having progressed to the next year, or whether they are appearing for the first time with a course year != 1.

Comment: Why is No = 1 if Year = 2019 and Course Years = 1,2? Please make an example in which not every row has NO of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from the description, but I think this may be helpful.

For each `ID`, you can create a new column `COURSE_YEARS` that would contain a character value of all `COURSE_YEAR` values for that `ID` separated by a comma. `unique` is included since it was mentioned you needed `distinct` based on `group`.

A `filter` is added, so results will only include the first `YEAR` for a given `ID`.

Then, you can `group_by` both `YEAR` and `COURSE_YEARS` and `summarise` to get the number `n` of each of these combinations.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(COURSE_YEARS = toString(unique(COURSE_YEAR))) %>%
  filter(YEAR == first(YEAR)) %>%
  group_by(YEAR, COURSE_YEARS) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

**Output**

```
   YEAR COURSE_YEARS     n
  <int> <chr>        <int>
1  2019 1                1
2  2019 1, 2             1
3  2019 2                1
4  2019 2, 3             1
5  2019 3                1
```